# Text position on canvas is different in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-canvas

I need to draw a text string at a precise position on HTML5 canvas.

[Here's my test code](https://jsfiddle.net/mL3g8rmr/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="320" height="240" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");      
      ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      ctx.font = '100px Arial';
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)';
      ctx.fillText('Test', 0, 0);
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The margin at the top is different in Chrome and Firefox:
[image: Text in Chrome vs Firefox]

I'm going to draw other elements (e.g. images, shapes) on the canvas, and I need to make sure the text appears at the same position in all browsers. Is it possible?

Comment: probably the issue is with the text size when I changed it will work fine though I have tried using below and it's working fine with me ctx.font = "50px Verdana"; ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)'; ctx.fillText("Test", 10, 50);

Comment: @cracker I tried to change font as you suggested and the text position relative to the top of the canvas is still different in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I have tried using ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic"; ctx.fillText('Test', 10, 100); where you need to manually set the parameters. it might going to help you!

Answer (score 10):

**Cause**

As @iftah says: This mis-alignment is caused by a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852).

Please add your voice to the Firefox's bug page so they fix it soon.

**Workaround**

(Unfortunately), The workaround is to draw the text on a second canvas and scan that pixel data to find the topmost & leftmost pixel of the text.

Then draw the text on the main canvas but pulled upward and leftward by the calculated pixel offsets.

**Here is annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// test vars
var text='Test';
var fontsize=100;
var fontface='arial';

drawTextAtXY(0,0,text,fontsize,fontface,'black');

function drawTextAtXY(x,y,text,fontsize,fontface,fill){
    // find the leftmost & topmost pixel of the text
    var minXY=getTextTop(text,fontsize,fontface);
    // set the font styles
    ctx.textBaseline='top';
    ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    // draw the text
    // Pull the text leftward and topward by minX & minY
    ctx.fillText(text,x-minXY.x,y-minXY.y);
}


function getTextTop(text,fontsize,fontface){
    // create temp working canvas
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var w=canvas.width;
    var h=fontsize*2;
    c.width=w;
    c.height=h;
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    // set font styles
    cctx.textBaseline='top';
    cctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
    cctx.fillStyle='red';
    // draw the text
    cctx.fillText(text,0,0);
    // get pixel data
    var imgdata=cctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var d=imgdata.data;
    // scan pixel data for minX,minY
    var minX=10000000;
    var minY=minX;
    for(var y=0;y<h;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<w;x++){
        var n=(y*w+x)*4
        if(d[n+3]>0){
            if(y<minY){minY=y;}
            if(x<minX){minX=x;}
        }
    }}
    // return the leftmost & topmost pixel of the text
    return({x:minX,y:minY});
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Text drawn exactly at specified X,Y</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: And i though creating a big image of the chrome page and loading that with an image-map would be a lot of work...

Comment: @ThrowingDwarf. Yep, browser-compatible===good, (browser-incompatible || browser-glitches)===PITA. :-)

Comment: Some update about this, ( the bug report finally came back to life :-) ) : It could actually be a bug in other browsers https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852#c20

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it easily.

you can use textBaseline = "middle";
and must use transform to 50px of top

means:

```
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="320" height="240" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");      
          ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
          ctx.font = '100px Arial';
          ctx.textAlign = 'left';
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
          ctx.save();
          ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 50);
          ctx.fillText('Test', 0, 0);
          ctx.restore();
       }
    </script>
```

A another bug is in your code: rgba(0, 0, 0, **255**)
fourth number in rgba must be between 0-1 for example 0.75.

why I write .save() and .restore() ?
for reset transform and clear after use it.

Of course you can use

```
ctx.fillText('Test', 0, 50);
```

Instead

```
ctx.save();
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 50);
ctx.fillText('Test', 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Firefox dating back to 2012 and still not fixed!

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852

*Edit:* 
Setting the baseLine to "alphabetic" (the default) results in both Chrome and Firefox having the same vertical location for the text.

*Edit:* 
Unfortunately, the vertical location isn't the only difference between Firefox and Chrome. Changing the string to "Testing" shows clearly that not only is the vertical location different, but also the space between the letters is slightly different - resulting in different width of the text.

If you really must have pixel perfect location AND size of the text maybe you should use [Bitmap fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other answer it's some king of bug (or maybe just a different implementation). textBaseline bottom and Y position to 100 can fix it.

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="320" height="240" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");      
      ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
      ctx.font = '100px Arial';
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(150, 50, 0, 1)';
      ctx.fillText('Test', 0, 100);
   }
</script>
```

In general: Use baseline bottom and increase Y position the font size amount