# Differences in Line Height and Position When Rendering Text with Canvas Across Browsers and Platforms

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-browser, cross-platform, konvajs

I've encountered a subtle issue while rendering text using Canvas on different browsers (Cairo (Node-Canvas), WebKit, Chromium) and operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux). The line height and text positioning seem to vary slightly. Even within the same browser, like Chrome, there are minor differences across these platforms.

To illustrate the issue, I've used Konva.js to draw grids and text, allowing for an easier comparison of the rendering differences across environments.

Code Example:

```js
import { Stage, Layer } from "konva";

// 一格的邊長多少px
const CELL_SIZE = 16;
// 有多少格
const GRID_SIZE = [50, 50];
// 作業區大小
const WORKAREA_SIZE = GRID_SIZE.map((size) => size * CELL_SIZE);

const stage = new Stage({
  container: document.getElementById("app"),
  width: WORKAREA_SIZE[0],
  height: WORKAREA_SIZE[1],
});
const bgLayer = new Layer();
const drawLayer = new Layer();

// 底色
const bgRect = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: WORKAREA_SIZE[0],
  height: WORKAREA_SIZE[1],
  fill: "#5f5f5f",
  listening: false,
});
bgLayer.add(bgRect);

// 網格
const verticalLines = Array.from({ length: GRID_SIZE[0] + 1 }, (_, i) => {
  const x = i * CELL_SIZE;
  return new Konva.Line({
    points: [x, 0, x, WORKAREA_SIZE[1]],
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 1,
  });
});
const horizontalLines = Array.from({ length: GRID_SIZE[1] + 1 }, (_, i) => {
  const y = i * CELL_SIZE;
  return new Konva.Line({
    points: [0, y, WORKAREA_SIZE[0], y],
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 1,
  });
});
bgLayer.add(...verticalLines, ...horizontalLines);

// 文字
const textNode = new Konva.Text({
  fill: "red",
  draggable: true,
  text: "Hello",
  fontSize: 16 * CELL_SIZE,
});
drawLayer.add(textNode);

stage.add(bgLayer);
stage.add(drawLayer);
stage.batchDraw();
```

[Sample on CodeSandbox demonstrating the issue.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/konva-playground-forked-qgprmm?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A22%2C27)

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Wog.jpg)

I was hoping to find a way to render text using Canvas that would look consistent across all browsers and platforms. If this is currently not possible, are there alternative solutions? For instance, would using WebGL or OpenGL + WASM help?

Comment: My hunch is that this comes down to the default font and possibly even it's specific implementation on a given platform, which might differ in terms of spacing. Have you tried using a Google Font for example?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using different fonts, such as DotGothic16 and Cubic11. It appears they were successfully loaded as the text became quite pixelized, which is characteristic of these fonts. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue – the positioning inconsistencies across different platforms and browsers still persisted.

Comment: P.S.: I am working on an application that allows users to edit LED panels. For static content, it's feasible to convert the canvas to base64 on the client-side and then process it. However, the challenge arises with dynamic content that requires polling updates on the server-side. For this purpose, I have to use node-canvas or Puppeteer to render the canvas on the backend. This leads to a situation where, if the user's OS/browser configuration differs from my server's, the rendered content might not match what the user sees or expects...

Comment: Not specifically a Konva issue - relates to canvas implementation on different platforms. Some previous questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379392/placing-text-on-html5-canvas-inconsistent-across-browsers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931800/text-position-on-canvas-is-different-in-firefox-and-chrome.

Comment: It seems quite challenging to maintain consistency for canvas across different devices... I also found the term 'canvas fingerprinting', which shows that canvas can even be used to track device...

Comment: ok...I have a unperfect solution now. First, draw an engilsh letter "A" at both client and server side. Then calc the top point of "A" as offset.

Comment: [my solution git](https://github.com/soapproject/offset-canvas-demo/tree/main?fbclid=IwAR281glDEGrq6g4lGeG19LG4wZmhnr_f3fYxFzElSsO37WOOgAJoQAjkVvc)